Gathering data from specific sheets in Excel based on date range with preceeding sheets being monthly data
So I have an Excel document. Each sheet contains data in specific locations for that month. This means that for each month's sheet, the specific value for a certain item is always in the same cell.
What I'm looking to do is have a sheet at the start or end of the document that lets a user specify how many month's worth of data they want to compare, then it can check the specific sheets within the range of that many months (so because today is May 27th, if I specified 6 months, it could take the data from Nov 23, Dec 23, Jan 24, Feb 24, Mar 24, Apr 24 and May 24, then using the data from those months a chart for the data could be made to visually compare each item on a month by month basis.
I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I'm drawing blanks right now. I initially thought that I could start by having cell A1 on each sheet being the date for the first of the month for each month, but then was trying to work out the best way to go from there.
EDIT: Here's some sample data showing the way the data is laid out in the actual spreadsheet I'm working on to give an example of how it would need to pull the data.

Hey @Louise ,, Filter data on month/Dates is not a big issue,,,, but whether U wanna whole month data or within specific Dates,,,, better share some sample data will help me & others to suggest a good solution ☺

Hi @RajeshSinha Thanks for your comment. I've added in a spreadsheet with sample data.

So, there may be more better ways of doing this, however this is what I have tried and came up with:


• Formula used in cell B4
=REDUCE({"Month","Day","Customers"},TOCOL(TAKE(DROP(SHEETNAME,,-1),,-(B2+1))), 
 LAMBDA(r,c, VSTACK(r, HSTACK(EXPAND(c,7,,""),INDIRECT("'"&c&"'!C6:D12")))))


Before entering the formula in cell B4 create a defined name in the Name Managers using the following and name it as SHEETNAME:
=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")


• Alternative for the above formula using TEXTAFTER():
=TEXTAFTER(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"]")



The SHEETNAME() is a custom defined function which uses Excel Macro 4.0 function GET.WORKBOOK() to instantly add sheets whenever is added in the workbook.
Next, Using REDUCE() with the help of INDIRECT() listing all the records for the Customers data(NOTE: For the Product and Sales I have not shown, because you can follow the steps to create on your own, basically you need to change the range in the INDIRECT() function from C6:D12 to C17:D25.) 
The REDUCE() will list all the records for the no. of months based on cell B2 plus the present month.
To make it more dynamic, I have created two more defined names in the Name Manager one is Customer and the other MonthsDays, what it does, it excludes any 0 values and returns till the last row data.


• For Customers use:
=$D$5:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTIF(INDEX(DROP($B$4#,1),,3),"<>0")+4)


• For MonthsDays use:
=$B$5:INDEX($B:$C,COUNTIF(INDEX(DROP($B$4#,1),,2),"<>0")+4,)



From, Insert Tab, create a 2D Column Chart, based on the data in cell >kbd>B4
Select the Chart goto ChartDesign Tab and select Select Data
Change the Legend Entries Series to ='Test Data.xlsx'!Customers and the Horizontal Axis Lables to ='Test Data.xlsx'!MonthsDays


NOTES: It is always suggested to avoid volatile functions, as they slow down the working functionalities of Excel as well as will keep recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook, therefore I have posted an alternative below. And more importantly since the above functions uses Excel Macro 4.0 the workbook needs to be saved as .xlsm or .xlsb. The formulas are MS365 Exclusive.

• Alternaitve Method One: The following will return the same output as REDUCE()
=VSTACK({"Month","Day","Customer"},
 TAKE(HSTACK(TOCOL(EXPAND(DROP(TOCOL(SHEETNAME),-1),,7,"")), 
 VSTACK('May 23:May 24'!C6:D12)),-((B2+1)*7)))


• Alternative Method Two: If you are aware that there will be fixed number of sheets and starting month is already confirmed then could use this one as well, this doesn't involves Excel Macro 4.0 as well as no Volatile functions.
=VSTACK({"Month","Day","Customer"},
 TAKE(HSTACK(TOCOL(EXPAND(TEXT(DATE(2023,SEQUENCE(13,,5),1),"mmm yy"),,7,"")),
 VSTACK('May 23:May 24'!C6:D12)),-((B2+1)*7))) 


The workbook can be downloaded from here: Link


Ooh, thanks for the advice. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

@LouiseWade any update? Have you made it worked, i have added a worksheet as well, click on the word says link.

It worked and I was bale to rewrite it for the actual data. You've been a huge help. I did give your answer an upvote, but it won't recognise it because I'm a new user.
